# Cant Scrape data from table using Puppeteer. It returns Empty Array

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I've been trying to scrape data from a table using `puppeteer` but I always get an empty array.
Please help as I am a noob with `puppeteer` and spent many days on it already.
The process is the following.

1. login into the website
2. There is an annoying banner that opens once we log in (Sometimes code get stuck in there)
3. Move to a different page to access financial report data
4. Click on Button (Paid Bills) and change the date range filter to load the data by clicking on the Button Filter.
5. Scrape the data table and reproduce it as a table. (Later this will be moved to a database)

I've tried many different ways and it's returning an empty array or sometimes console is not showing anything.

Please see the data structure from the website.

```
<div class="scroll-wrapper" data-ng-init="reportController.adjustScroll()">
   <div class="scroll-top">
      <div class="dummy-div" style="width: 743px;">
         <table class="table-report">
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th class="td-4 text-left" ng-class="{'active': reportController.propertyName === 'ContableAccount'}" ng-click="reportController.sortBy('ContableAccount')">
                     CONTA
                     <span class="sortorder sprite-report arrow-order-grey" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}"></span>
                  </th>
                  <th class="td-7 text-left" ng-class="{'active': reportController.propertyName === 'Description'}" ng-click="reportController.sortBy('Description')">
                     DESCRIÇÃO
                     <span class="sortorder sprite-report arrow-order-grey" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}"></span>
                  </th>
                  <th class="td-5 text-left" ng-class="{'active': reportController.propertyName === 'Supplier'}" ng-click="reportController.sortBy('Supplier')">
                     FORNECEDOR
                     <span class="sortorder sprite-report arrow-order-grey" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}"></span>
                  </th>
                  <th class="td-3 text-left active" ng-class="{'active': reportController.propertyName === 'DueDate'}" ng-click="reportController.sortBy('DueDate')">
                     VENCIMENTO
                     <span class="sortorder sprite-report arrow-order-grey" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}"></span>
                  </th>
                  <!-- ngIf: reportController.listParameters.Paid -->
                  <th class="td-3 text-left" ng-class="{'active': reportController.propertyName === 'Total'}" ng-click="reportController.sortBy('Total')">
                     TOTAL
                     <span class="sortorder sprite-report arrow-order-grey" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}"></span>
                  </th>
                  <th class="td-3 text-left" ng-class="{'active': reportController.propertyName === 'Paid'}" ng-click="reportController.sortBy('Paid')">
                     PAGO
                     <span class="sortorder sprite-report arrow-order-grey" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}"></span>
                  </th>
                  <th class="td-3 text-left" ng-class="{'active': reportController.propertyName === 'Balance'}" ng-click="reportController.sortBy('Balance')">
                     SALDO
                     <span class="sortorder sprite-report arrow-order-grey" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}"></span>
                  </th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="scroll-bottom">
      <div class="content-div ng-isolate-scope" infinite-scroll="reportController.getMoreRecords()" infinite-scroll-distance="1">
         <table class="table-report">
            <tbody>
               <!-- ngRepeat: item in reportController.listDataLocal | orderBy:reportController.propertyName:reportController.reverse -->
               <tr ng-repeat="item in reportController.listDataLocal | orderBy:reportController.propertyName:reportController.reverse" class="ng-scope">
                  <td class="td-4 text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="Mercadoria para Revenda">Mercadoria para Revenda</td>
                  <td class="td-7 text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="Pedido de Compra Nº 1966">Pedido de Compra Nº 1966</td>
                  <td class="td-5 text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="Oderco Distribuidora Eletronicos Ltda">Oderco Distribuidora Eletronicos Ltda</td>
                  <td class="td-3 text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="27/05/2020">27/05/2020</td>
                  <!-- ngIf: reportController.listParameters.Paid -->
                  <td class="td-3 text-right text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="R$ 436,02">R$ 436,02</td>
                  <td class="td-3 text-right text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="R$ 0,00">R$ 0,00</td>
                  <td class="td-3 text-right text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="R$ 436,02">R$ 436,02</td>
               </tr>
               <!-- end ngRepeat: item in reportController.listDataLocal | orderBy:reportController.propertyName:reportController.reverse -->
               <tr ng-repeat="item in reportController.listDataLocal | orderBy:reportController.propertyName:reportController.reverse" class="ng-scope">
                  <td class="td-4 text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="Mercadoria para Revenda">Mercadoria para Revenda</td>
                  <td class="td-7 text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="Pedido de Compra Nº 1965">Pedido de Compra Nº 1965</td>
                  <td class="td-5 text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="GIBSON SOLUÇÕES EM TECNOLOGIA LTDA">GIBSON SOLUÇÕES EM TECNOLOGIA LTDA</td>
                  <td class="td-3 text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="27/05/2020">27/05/2020</td>
                  <!-- ngIf: reportController.listParameters.Paid -->
                  <td class="td-3 text-right text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="R$ 480,52">R$ 480,52</td>
                  <td class="td-3 text-right text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="R$ 0,00">R$ 0,00</td>
                  <td class="td-3 text-right text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="R$ 480,52">R$ 480,52</td>
               </tr>
               <!-- end ngRepeat: item in reportController.listDataLocal | orderBy:reportController.propertyName:reportController.reverse -->
               <tr ng-repeat="item in reportController.listDataLocal | orderBy:reportController.propertyName:reportController.reverse" class="ng-scope">
                  <td class="td-4 text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="Água">Água</td>
                  <td class="td-7 text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="SAAE">SAAE</td>
                  <td class="td-5 text-ellipsis ng-binding" title=""></td>
                  <td class="td-3 text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="27/05/2020">27/05/2020</td>
                  <!-- ngIf: reportController.listParameters.Paid -->
                  <td class="td-3 text-right text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="R$ 35,77">R$ 35,77</td>
                  <td class="td-3 text-right text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="R$ 0,00">R$ 0,00</td>
                  <td class="td-3 text-right text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="R$ 35,77">R$ 35,77</td>
               </tr>
               <!-- end ngRepeat: item in reportController.listDataLocal | orderBy:reportController.propertyName:reportController.reverse -->
               <tr ng-repeat="item in reportController.listDataLocal | orderBy:reportController.propertyName:reportController.reverse" class="ng-scope">
                  <td class="td-4 text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="Mensalidade Escritório">Mensalidade Escritório</td>
                  <td class="td-7 text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="ESCRITORIO ITAPIRENSE">ESCRITORIO ITAPIRENSE</td>
                  <td class="td-5 text-ellipsis ng-binding" title=""></td>
                  <td class="td-3 text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="21/05/2020">21/05/2020</td>
                  <!-- ngIf: reportController.listParameters.Paid -->
                  <td class="td-3 text-right text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="R$ 240,00">R$ 240,00</td>
                  <td class="td-3 text-right text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="R$ 0,00">R$ 0,00</td>
                  <td class="td-3 text-right text-ellipsis ng-binding" title="R$ 240,00">R$ 240,00</td>
               </tr>
               <!-- end ngRepeat: item in reportController.listDataLocal | orderBy:reportController.propertyName:reportController.reverse -->
            </tbody>
         </table>
         <!-- ngIf: reportController.lastPage -->
         <table class="table-report footer ng-scope" ng-if="reportController.lastPage">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td class="td-12 text-left" colspan="3">Exibindo <span class="number ng-binding">4</span> registros</td>
                  <td class="td-7">&nbsp;</td>
                  <!-- ngIf: reportController.listParameters.Paid -->
                  <td class="td-3 ng-binding">R$ 1.192,31</td>
                  <td class="td-3 ng-binding">R$ 0,00</td>
                  <td class="td-3 ng-binding">R$ 1.192,31</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
         <!-- end ngIf: reportController.lastPage -->
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is my Puppeteer Code with comments.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  try {
    const websiteUrl = "mySite.com";

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
const page = await browser.newPage();

// prevent detection as robot
page.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.0 Safari/537.36");

await page.goto(websiteUrl);

//set the browser to be in desktop size and do not hide the login menu
await page.setViewport({ width: 2400, height: 1171 });

await page.waitForSelector("#login§ds_login");

//Type login details using fields IDS
await page.type("#login§ds_login", "myUsername");
await page.type("#login§ds_password", "myPassword");

await Promise.all([page.waitForNavigation(), page.click("#login§bt_login")]);

await page.waitForSelector('button[title="Fechar"]');
await page.click('button[title="Fechar"]');

await page.goto("page-where-tableIs.com", { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });

// Click on Button that says Paid Bills
await page.waitForSelector(".filter > .filters-container > .alternate-buttons > .buttons-center > .btn:nth-child(2)");
await page.click(".filter > .filters-container > .alternate-buttons > .buttons-center > .btn:nth-child(2)");

// select Date Range and click on filter button
await page.waitForSelector(".action-bar-container > .filters-container > .filter-date > .from > .ng-pristine");

await page.type(".action-bar-container > .filters-container > .filter-date > .from > .ng-pristine", "01012020");
await page.type(".action-bar-container > .filters-container > .filter-date > .to > .ng-pristine", "01052020");
await page.click(".filters-container > .filter-date > .confirm-filter > button > .sprite-new-erp");

// IF SWTICH ON CONSOLE DOESNT LOG ANYTHING
// await page.waitForNavigation({
//   waitUntil: "networkidle0"
// });

// I TRIED THIS AN ALTERNATIVE FOR THE ONE ABOVE AND IF TURNED ON NOTHING IS LOGGED TO CONSOLE
// await page.waitForSelector("tbody tr");

// Test Area (I've tried many codes as below and everything return an EMPTY ARRAY)

const test01 = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr")).map(partner => partner.textContent));
console.log(test01);

const test02 = await page.evaluate(() =>
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr")).map(rows => {
    const getData = child => rows.querySelector(`.td-${child}`).getAttribute("title");
    return [getData(2), getData(7), getData(5), getData(3), getData(7)];
  })
);

console.log(test02);

const test03 = await page.evaluate(() =>
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr")).map(rows => {
    const getData = child => rows.querySelector(`.td-5:nth-child(${child})`).getAttribute("title");
    return [getData(2), getData(7), getData(5), getData(3), getData(7)];
  })
);

console.log(test03);

const test04 = await page.evaluate(() =>
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("tbody > tr")).map(rows => {
    const getData = rows => team.querySelector(`td.td-${child}.text-ellipsis.ng-binding`).getAttribute("title");
    return [getData(2), getData(7), getData(5), getData(3), getData(7)];
  })
);
console.log(test04);

const test05 = page.evaluate(() => {
  const rows = document.querySelectorAll(".table-report tr td");
  return Array.from(rows, row => {
    const columns = row.querySelectorAll(".table-report tr th");
    return Array.from(columns, column => column.innerText);
  });
});

console.log(test05);

const simpleTest = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr")));

console.log(simpleTest);

const simpletest2 = simpleTest.writeToJson();
console.log(simpletest2);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("error", e);
  }

  await browser.close();
})();
```